# Fitting CSV data in Mathematica

Tags: csv, import, wolfram-mathematica

I have a [CSV file](http://pastebin.com/pPpVyAzN), please note you should copy and paste it and rename the file name to GPA.csv, and I would like to import that into Mathematica and fit it using a power function.

Note: I am aware that fitting it perfectly with a power function is very undesirable as it gives bad predictions.

So I began by doing the following:

```
data = Import["C:\\GPA.csv", "Table"]
linfit = Fit[data, {1,x}, x]
```

Now the strange thing is that it gives me an error stating:

> Fit::fitc: Number of coordinates (0) is not equal to the number of variables (1). >>

But I am sure I have entered more than 350 coordinates. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have also try to do test = Transpose[data], but then I get about 350 coordinates and it is still not equal to the number of variables.

Comment: See what `data[[1]] // FullForm` tells you.

Comment: It tells me the following: List["8.00,4.00"]

Comment: I meant it as a hint; compare importing with `"Table"` vs with `"Data"`.

Comment: Well I kind of fixed it, I shouldn't import it as Table, but as "CSV". This would give me the correct linear regression, however I cannot find the explanation / difference between Table and CSV. I thought both "datatypes" were the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer both of your questions:

1. `Import["C:\\GPA.CSV", "Data"]` will make everything work - as would simply `Import["C:\\GPA.CSV"]`.
2. The reason these things are different is because Mathematica has an unintuitive and (IMO) confusingly documented way of importing files. The specific reason `"Table"` didn't work was that this is being interpreted as the 'file format', and by default - see [the format documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Table.html) - `Import` assumes that in this case:

   ```
   "FieldSeparators" = {" ","\t"}
   ```

   so that your commas are actually assumed to be part of a string on each line, rather than a separator - only spaces and tabs are allowed. (This is much more confusing if you have a file containing `1, 2` in which case you get one string `"1,"` and one number `2`.) As a result, you could also use

   ```
   Import["C:\\GPA.CSV", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ","]
   ```

   The CSV file format, of course, assumes commas as the separator as you wanted. Confusingly, `"Data"`, in this context, is *not* a 'file format', but an 'element'. This means that the `.csv` file extension lets the file be imported as a CSV file, and then you request... wait for it... the 'data' element from the imported file. Which is the data.

You can try reading [the `Import` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html) and the [listing of formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) but I imagine you already tried.